# Rename [censor] → [censorship]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-rename-request

The tag [censor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/censor) should be renamed to [censorship](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/censorship), as censorship is the proper name for the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Okay](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/censorship).

Comment: Thanks. I've also put up a wiki for it. :)

Comment: @CyberSkull Thanks for all your contributions! I'm constantly impressed by your resolve.

Comment: Hey @Mana, could you mark this completed? Thanks for the compliment. :D